# Ckeditor удаляет/неправильно интерпретирует стили и формы

Tags: ckeditor, css

Есть:
а)вручную свёрстанная страница. 
б) ckeditor с подключенным файлом css

При загрузке страницы в ckeditor, пропадают элементы формы, некоторые стили неправильно интерпретируются, в общем, выглядит всё не так как надо, и если сохранить страницу в таком виде, то кирдык всему.

Может кто в курсе как настроить ckeditor или отучить его от самоуправства?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в конфиг добавить:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

[link text](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/datafiltering.html)